# json DeserializeObject in c# using json.net

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

Im having a problem deserializing some json I get from a webserver and I think it is beacuse of the formating.

The json look like this :

```
{
    "post_count": {
        "total_posts": 1,
        "sfw_total_posts": 1,
        "use": 0
    },
    "posts_per_page": 1,
    "posts": [
        {
            "guid": 10019127,
            "wp_id": 656197,
            "type": "media",
            "title": "Test",
            "path": "TestPath",
            "publish_start": 1385559021,
            "author": "Test",
            "web_url": "http://www.test.com",
            "nsfw": "No",
            "modified": 1385532803,
            "video": "No",
            "likes": 484,
            "dislikes": 51,
            "main_category_id": 71,
            "thumbnails": [
                {
                    "w": 120,
                    "h": 120
                },
                {
                    "w": 240,
                    "h": 240
                }
            ],
            "comments": 26
        }
    ],
    "server": "100.200",
    "time": 0.42163896560669
}
```

I have created a class with the value for there that I want to use and then using

```
LatestChive lastchives = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LatestChive>(jsonstring);
```

I try to deserialize it but all the values return null (I only want the stuff that is in "posts")

If I try with "post_count" or "posts_per_page" i can get the values just not from the the "posts"

I hope this makes sense and there is a easy fix thank you.

Comment: It would help if you showed your `LatestChive` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your classes as

```
public class PostCount
{
    public int total_posts { get; set; }
    public int sfw_total_posts { get; set; }
    public int use { get; set; }
}

public class Thumbnail
{
    public int w { get; set; }
    public int h { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int guid { get; set; }
    public int wp_id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string path { get; set; }
    public int publish_start { get; set; }
    public string author { get; set; }
    public string web_url { get; set; }
    public string nsfw { get; set; }
    public int modified { get; set; }
    public string video { get; set; }
    public int likes { get; set; }
    public int dislikes { get; set; }
    public int main_category_id { get; set; }
    public List<Thumbnail> thumbnails { get; set; }
    public int comments { get; set; }
}

public class LatestChive
{
    public PostCount post_count { get; set; }
    public int posts_per_page { get; set; }
    public List<Post> posts { get; set; }
    public string server { get; set; }
    public double time { get; set; }
}
```

For your future work see http://json2csharp.com/